# Chemical potential and its relation to entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, chemical-potential

If we consider the particle number $N$ as a variable then we have:

$$\mathrm dE=T\,\mathrm dS - P\,\mathrm dV + \mu\,\mathrm dN$$

From here we can find that:

$$\mu=\left(\frac {\partial E}{\partial N}\right)\Biggr|_{S,V}$$

But it is also equal to:

$$\mu= -T\left(\frac {\partial S}{\partial N}\right)\Biggr|_{E,V}$$

Can anyone explain to me, where does the 2nd equation come from?

Comment: The differentiation with respect to N is nearly identical; you just hold E constant instead of S.

Comment: Ok thx, I got it